# How to add row to a table based on selection in drop down and fill cells with selected number from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
<script>
  var itemCount = 0;
  
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#line').change(function(){
 var i;
 i = $("#line").val();   
      while(itemCount < i){ 
        var html = "";
 

        itemCount++;
        // dynamically create rows in the table
        html = "<tr id='tr"+ itemCount + "'><td></td> <td></td> <td></td><td><input type='button'  id='" + itemCount + "' value='remove'></td> </tr>";            
         
        //add to the table
   
        $("#bill_table").append(html)

        // The remove button click
        $("#"+itemCount).click(function() {
            var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
            //write the logic for removing from the array
            $("#tr"+ buttonId).remove();
   itemCount--;

        });

           }  
    });
     
 });
  
     
</script>
```

```css
#selction{list-style: none;}
#selction li {float: right;}
#selction li a {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<select id="line">
 <option value="select rows">select rows</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<div class="number-list">
    <ul id="selction">
        <li><a id="n1" class="s" onclick="ButtonSelected('n1')" role="button" value="1">1</a></li>
        <li><a id="n2" onclick="ButtonSelected('n2')" role="button" value="2">2</a></li>
        <li><a id="n3" onclick="ButtonSelected('n3')" role="button" value="3">3</a></li>
        <li><a id="n4" onclick="ButtonSelected('n4')" role="button">4</a></li>
        <li><a id="n5" onclick="ButtonSelected('n5')" role="button">5</a></li>
        <li><a id="n6" onclick="ButtonSelected('n6')" role="button">6</a></li>
        <li><a id="n7" onclick="ButtonSelected('n7')" role="button">7</a></li>
        <li><a id="n8" onclick="ButtonSelected('n8')" role="button">8</a></li>
        <li><a id="n9" onclick="ButtonSelected('n9')" role="button">9</a></li>
        <li><a id="n10" onclick="ButtonSelected('n10')" role="button">10</a></li>
        <li><a id="n11" onclick="ButtonSelected('n11')" role="button">11</a></li>
        <li><a id="n12" onclick="ButtonSelected('n12')" role="button">12</a></li>
        <li><a id="n13" onclick="ButtonSelected('n13')" role="button">13</a></li>
        <li><a id="n14" onclick="ButtonSelected('n14')" role="button">14</a></li>
        <li><a id="n15" onclick="ButtonSelected('n15')" role="button">15</a></li>
        <li><a id="n16" onclick="ButtonSelected('n16')" role="button">16</a></li>
        <li><a id="n17" onclick="ButtonSelected('n17')" role="button">17</a></li>
        <li><a id="n18" onclick="ButtonSelected('n18)" role="button">19</a></li>
        <li><a id="n19" onclick="ButtonSelected('n19')" role="button">20</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
 
<div class="table-wrapper">
 
<table border='1' id='bill_table'  width='50%' align='center'  style='border-collapse:collapse' cellspacing='3' cellpadding='5'>
 
</table>

</div>
```

I have a big problem and I searched for solution but I couldn't fix or write my code.Any help would be appreciated!

I want create **dynamic table** ,I have a `<select></select>` drop down and when user selects a number from drop down ,the table `should create rows.`

For example when we select `4`, table should have `4 rows` or when we select `1` table should have just one row.

and I have list of numbers,when user select a number,this selected number have to be shown in table

and finally have a `delete button` when we select a row and click on this button, the selected row have to be deleted.

Comment: Did you even try to write some JavaScript or jQuery? Like `ButtonSelected()`?

Comment: i have code for button selected and it works .and i write codes for adding rows and input content on it but it didnt work.i'll add my javascript to my post.could you help me to correct it?

Comment: Sure I'll give it a shot.

Comment: i added javascript code!could you help me please

Comment: where is the code? I see people referencing code down in the answers but there is none in the questions anymore

Comment: i added code now! i edited it and now jq works for adding rows and deleting selected row! bur still didnt write code for inserting selected buttons value to table.colud you help please?

Answer (score 1):

#### UPDATE

The button numbers input whatever makes very little sense. In Snippet 2 there's a simple table and 9 buttons. Each button will insert it's number into the appropriate cell.

---

I didn't quite conform to all of your requests because I thought there's a better way to go about things:

- Replaced `while` loop with a `for` loop.
- There was never a `#bill_table` to append anything to, so you should test it and make sure that the elements in HTML match to what's in JS/jQ.
- Didn't understand what purpose the `ButtonSelected()` function was for so got rid of it.
- In order to select the rows for removal I added a checkbox for each row, and line0 has an all check/uncheck feature as well.
- Didn't see a point in keeping an array and not using it, so I added a log feature:

  - The log is supported by 2 utility functions:
  - `removeByKV()` - Removes objects from an array by key/value
  - `logItems()` - Appends strings to log and automatically scrolls to the end
- Added an editor that will insert text at a given line/cell position within the table.

#### SNIPPET 1

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>tableGen</title>
  <style>
  #table1 {
    width: 100%;
    /*direction: rtl;*/
    border-collapse: separate;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 30px auto;
  }
  
  #table1 tbody tr td {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20px;
  }
  
  #table1 tbody tr th {
    height: 20px;
    background: #1256ef;
    color: #fff;
  }
  
  footer {
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100vw;
  }
  
  .log b {
    font-family: Consolas;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .log {
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 60px;
    width: 500px;
    display: block;
  }
  
  input {
    width: 5ex;
  }

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <label for='rowQty1'>Number of Rows: </label>
    <input id='rowQty1' type='number' max='20' min='1'>
    <button id="addRows1">Add Row(s)</button>
  </header>
  <section>
    <table id="table1">
      <tbody>
        <tr id='tr0'>
          <th><input id='CHX1' type="checkbox"> Line0
          </th>
          <td id='tr0td1'>&nbsp;</td>
          <td id='tr0td2'>&nbsp;</td>
          <td id='tr0td3'>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td><button id="delRow1">Delete Row(s)</button></td>
          <td colspan='3'>
            <label for='tr'>Line: <input id='tr' type='number' min='0'></label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label for='td'>Cell: <input id='td' type='number' min='1' max='3'></label><br/>
            <textarea class='editor' rows='4' cols='40'></textarea><br/>
            <button id='addContent1'>Add Content</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </section>
  <footer>
    <output class='log'></output>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var qty = 1;
    var itemSerial = 0;
    var html = '';
    var msg = '';
    var itemArray = [];
    $('#addRows1').on('click', function() {
      var numRows = Number($('#rowQty1').val());
      for(let i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        itemSerial++;
        qty++;
        var obj = {
          "ROW_ID": "tr" + itemSerial
        };
        // add object
        itemArray.push(obj);
        // dynamically create rows in the table
        html = '<tr id="tr' + itemSerial +
          '"><th><input class="chx" type="checkbox">Line' +
          itemSerial +
          '</th> <td id="tr' + itemSerial +
          'td1">&nbsp;</td> <td id="tr' + itemSerial +
          'td2">&nbsp;</td><td id="tr' + itemSerial +
          'td3">&nbsp;</td> </tr>';
        //add to the table
        $("#table1").append(html);
      }
      msg += '<b> ' + numRows + ' ADDED; TOTAL ITEMS: ' +
        qty + '</b>';
      logItems(msg);
    });
    $('#CHX1').on('change', function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.chx').each(function() {
          $(this).prop('checked', true);
        });
      } else {
        $('.chx').each(function() {
          $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
      }
    });
    // The remove button click
    $("#delRow1").click(function() {
      $('.chx:checked').each(function() {
        var row = $(this).closest('tr');
        var rowID = row.attr('id');
        row.remove();
        removeByKV(itemArray, {
          key: "ROW_ID",
          value: rowID
        });
        qty--;
        msg += '<b> ROW_ID: ' + rowID +
          ' REMOVED; TOTAL ITEMS: ' + qty +
          '</b>'
      });
      logItems(msg);
    });
    $('#addContent1').on('click', function() {
      var line = $('#tr').val();
      var cell = $('#td').val();
      var text = $('.editor').val();
      $('#tr' + line + 'td' + cell).text(text);
    });

    function removeByKV(arr, keyVal) {
      arr.some(function(item, idx) {
        if(arr[idx][keyVal.key] === keyVal.value) {
          arr.splice(idx, 1);
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
      return arr;
    }

    function logItems(str) {
      $('.log').append(str);
      $('.log').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.log').prop("scrollHeight")
      }, 500);
    }
  });

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### SNIPPET 2

```js
$('thead button').on('click', function(e) {
  var num = $(this).data('id');
  var cell = $('tbody > tr > td').eq(num - 1);
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101)
  cell.text(rand);
});
```

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 96vw;
}
td {
  border: 2px dashed red;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan='4'>
        <button data-id='1'>1</button>
        <button data-id='2'>2</button>
        <button data-id='3'>3</button>
        <button data-id='4'>4</button>
        <button data-id='5'>5</button>
        <button data-id='6'>6</button>
        <button data-id='7'>7</button>
        <button data-id='8'>8</button>
        <button data-id='9'>9</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Line1</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Line2</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Line3</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks. its close to what i want but there is problems.i have corrected me correct my html and JQ codes..look at my html please. i have list of numbers and  i want when user click on number for exmaple button has number 2 ,this number be palced in table colmn1 row 1 and when select another number it be placed in row1 col2 and so on .i put delet button for each line myself so we dont need to chekbox for each row anymore!

Comment: Have you tried the editor? It has greater range than a button. The checkbox is advantageous because you can check all of them at once by checking line0 checkbox at top. BTW, why do you have an array? When you remove an item in your code, the array is unchanged. In my code the array is changed to reflect any additions or removal of items.

Comment: how insert value of list buttons in list#select li a in to table? do you have any idea?

Comment: You're very welcome. If this answer resolved the problem, click the green ✔

Comment: thanks again! if we want to select numbers random and fill table what we have to do.i mean it's not necessary wen we select 7form list,this be put in td id #7.could you help again?

Comment: If you have any additional questions you should post a new one. Review Snippet 2 each button will insert a random number between 1 to 100 to it's corresponding cell.

Comment: Sorry, that's a random number 0 to 100. BTW your code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i corrected my code myself.but still can't insert values of selected buttons in to table!

```js
<script>
  var itemCount = 0;
  
 $(document).ready(function(){
  
    var objs=[];
    var temp_objs=[];
     
    $('#line').change(function(){
 var i;
 i = $("#line").val();   
      while(itemCount < i){ 
        var html = "";
         
        var obj={
            "ROW_ID" : itemCount,

        }   

        // add object
        objs.push(obj);
                     
        itemCount++;
        // dynamically create rows in the table
        html = "<tr id='tr"+ itemCount + "'><td>"+ obj['ITEM_NAME'] + "</td> <td>" +  obj['ITEM_PRICE'] + " </td> <td>" +  obj['ITEM_QUANTITY'] + " </td><td><input type='button'  id='" + itemCount + "' value='remove'></td> </tr>";            
         
        //add to the table
   
        $("#bill_table").append(html)

        // The remove button click
        $("#"+itemCount).click(function() {
            var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");
            //write the logic for removing from the array
            $("#tr"+ buttonId).remove();
   itemCount--;

        });
           }  
    });
     
 });
  
     
</script>
<script>
var SelectCount=0;
 function ButtonSelected(id) {
  if (SelectCount < 6) {
   document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor="#006e0d";
   document.getElementById(id).style.color="#fff";
   SelectCount+=1;
   
  }
 }

</script>
```